# Mongoose callback never reached when saving

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose, save

For some reason the callback function is never called when a try to save data to the MongoDB database using Mongoose. First I thought that no error code was fired, but then I tested whether the callback function was entered at all, and it wasn't! And nothing is saved in the database. I can't even see a file named client-db in the folder where other MongoDB databases are stored (via commandline) - could that be the problem?

I've tried different solutions from similar problems, but nothing has worked so far. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I appeciate any help!

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

client-db.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/client-db', function(){
  console.log("Client DB: connected"); // This is shown
});

module.exports = mongoose;
//module.exports = db; // Another problem was solved by this, but didn't work for me
```

plot-data.js:

```
var db = require('client-db');

var plotDataSchema = db.Schema({
  time: {type: Number, required: true},
  value: {type: Number}
});

var PlotData = db.model('PlotData', plotDataSchema);

module.exports = PlotData;
```

controller.js:

```
var PlotData = require('plot-data');

//data is an object with time and value

var plotData = new PlotData({
  time: data.time,
  value: data.value
});

plotData.save(function(err){
  console.log('Entered callback'); // Never shown
  if(err){
    console.log(err); // Never shown
    //return handleErrror(err); // Different things I tried when I thought the error handling was the problem - didn't change anything
    //return next(err);
  }else{
    console.log('Plot data saved in client db'); // Never shown
  }
});
```

Comment: Pass `err` as a parameter in your mongoose.connect() callback e.g. `var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/client-db', function(err){`. Then, inside the callback, is `err` defined and if so what is the value?

Comment: It gave me an error, and I figured out I just needed to manually start mongod from commandline before running the node.js app. Problem solved - thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really are connected then it looks like you have a race condition going on with the DB connection and the save operation. Condensing your code to single file and executing the save within the connection callback works.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var plotDataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  time: {type: Number, required: true},
  value: {type: Number}
});
var PlotData = mongoose.model('PlotData', plotDataSchema);
var plotData = PlotData({
  time: 1234,
  value: 5678
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/client-db', function(err) {
  if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
  console.log("Client DB: connected"); // This is shown

  plotData.save(function(err, plot){
    console.log(err, plot);
    // outputs
    // null { __v: 0, time: 1234, value: 5678, _id: 5526892bcffa7a0e973fb456 }
  });
});
```

Also a couple of notes about Mongoose in general:

- It has an internal global cache for models, schemas and connections (as well as a cache per connection) so there is no need to do this: `module.exports = mongoose;`. Just require mongoose wherever you need it(node also has its own cache so it will just export the already existing mongoose to the requesting file).
- Following up on the above point, because of this internal cache for models you don't need to do this: `module.exports = PlotData`. Just require mongoose and then you can do: `var PlotData = mongoose.model('PlotData');` to retrieve the model from the cache.

So your files would look something like:

**client-db.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/client-db', function(err){
  if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
  console.log("Client DB: connected"); // This is shown
});
```

**plot-data.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var plotDataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  time: {type: Number, required: true},
  value: {type: Number}
});

mongoose.model('PlotData', plotDataSchema);
```

**controller.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var PlotData = mongoose.model('PlotData'); // Notice schema is not specified

var plotData = new PlotData({
  time: data.time,
  value: data.value
});

// NEED TO WAIT FOR CONNECTION BEFORE CALLING
plotData.save(function(err, plot){
  console.log(err, plot);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was that the database wasn't started, but you have some good points that I'll keep in mind :)

Comment: No problem. If you found the answer helpful and think other users might as well could you mark it as accepted to help them in case they stumble across this question?

Comment: The problem was the database connection, so I think it would be misleading to mark this as the correct answer. The correct answer is JoGoFo's comment. But I still appreciate your help.